# Convert a MFRC522 arduino chip to an USB device

Tags: c, arduino, driver, rfid

I'm tying to convert a [MFRC522](https://kostyanoysa.ru/bl-content/uploads/pages/b34d26eece6b53ff9cd8a2a2e68901e2/MFRC522.jpg) arduino chip to an USB device so as to use it natively on windows (with a cli or software) and without an Arduino. I don't know if I was clear (sorry for my bad english). Can anyone help me to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't do that because you need some mediation between the RFID reader and the PC USB port.

You don't have to use Arduino, but you do need a processor to "translate" the information from the reader and some hardware to speak to USB.

Comment: Okay, do you have an alternative to Arduino ? (not a Raspberry)

Comment: Any Arduino compatible you can find at your favorite Chinese supplier like this $2 device: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32821902128.html